# Is the sun required for evaporation?

Tags: temperature, molecules

I understand that the sun would heat up a pool of water causing the overall temperature to increase. This would also mean that more molecules would have enough energy to escape the pool, but wouldn't evaporation happen in the dark or in a place where the temperature is constant?

Comment: Evaporation as a phase transition depends on temperature and pressure. As long as these are suitable, there will be evaporation, no matter if it's because of the Sun or in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At normal atmospheric pressure, all you need for evaporation to occur is the addition of heat, which can come from whatever heat source you have handy, which includes the sun. If you want evaporation to proceed to dryness, then you also require low humidity conditions.